# Firebase sign in with email link giving ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am setting up a password-less environment for my Flutter app and I am having issues with the FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInWithEmailLink command.

```
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
    email: email,
    url: url// Using whitelisted url,
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOSBundleID: bundleId // bundle id for ios app,
    androidPackageName: androidId // package name for android,
    androidInstallIfNotAvailable: false,
    androidMinimumVersion: "18",
  );
```

The error I get is the following:

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN, Domain not whitelisted by project, null))

Even though the url I have attempted to us is on the white list under Authentication > Sign In Methods > Authorized Domains.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the domain of `url` in the list of authorized domains for your project?